# Search words in any order using "Like" query

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have a students table with following rows in it.

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Smith |
| 2 | Hellen Fernandis |
| 3 | Ali Abbas |
| 4 | Sameer Khan |

I want that even if I use the below mentioned query

```
Select * from students where name like '%Abbas Ali%'
```

Row No. 3 should come in result.

Comment: You need to state your question/what problem you have.

Comment: Ok, Got my answer from other place. I can use REGEXP instead, So new query would be 
Select * from students where name REGEXP 'Abbas|Ali'

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it in a single `LIKE`, you need multiple conditions:

```
WHERE name LIKE '%Abbas%' AND name LIKE '%Ali%'
```

Comment: If there is one more row in table with `name` is `Ali Abbas khan`. then it  will returns two result.the question will not solve in that way.

Comment: Why shouldn't it return that row? It contains the search words. He didn't say that it has to contain **only** those words.

Comment: yes, I agree with you but according to that question i think that he want to know how to get data if we suffle the `firstname` and `sirname`.

Comment: I'll wait for the OP to come back and say what he really wants.

Comment: I am ok with @Barmar answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you to do it in other manner, just try this:

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE name LIKE '%Abbas' AND name LIKE 'Ali%'
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Select * from students where name like '%Abbas%Ali%'
```